# Run Django without Apache using runserver on port 80 and accessible outside LAN

Tags: django, apache

In debugging mode, I can run django web that can be accessed by public (inside LAN) with:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

So, is it possible to run it directly on port 80 (maybe with a domain) like normally webserver does? If yes, is it a bad idea? I mean, is it better to use apache with `mod_wsgi`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its possible, but its a really bad idea because the default  server that django ships with does not support multiproccessing etc, and is meant solely for development.

As the [documentation notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server):

> Now’s a good time to note: DON’T use this server in anything resembling a production environment. It’s intended only for use while developing. (We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers.)

As for the choice of web server, do have a look at the [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12.html) to get more ideas around how to go ahead with it.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible. You can do it like this:

```
python manage.py runserver yourdomain.com:80
```

Whether it is a bad idea, it may depend on your use case. Generally I would recommend using e.g. apache or nginx for long-term running production environment though. It will surely perform better.

Comment: I get this error any way to get through? `Error: You don't have permission to access that port.`

Answer (score 2):

If you are needing to more easily debug an issue specifically when using similar environment to deployment, but still have it run on port 80, then presuming the system Apache is shut down and so not using port 80 at the time, then have a look at mod_wsgi-express.

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

For information on better integrating mod_wsgi-express with Django and using it for debugging see:

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/introducing-modwsgi-express.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/using-modwsgi-express-with-django.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/integrating-modwsgi-express-as-django.html
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/05/using-modwsgi-express-as-development.html

Answer (score 0):

Sound like two questions there.

1. *Is it possible?* **Yes** (see @geckon's answer).
2. *Is it **wise** to run a debug-friendly lightweight development server in production?* : **No**

But luckily there's plenty of official documentation on [running Apache with mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/), so that shouldn't be too hard.