# How do I link my Route53 domain name to an application running on an EC2 instance on a specific port?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I've a django application deployed on an ec2 instance (with public IP a.b.c.d) on port 8080 and have a domain name 'xyz.com' purchased via Route53. How do I link the domain name to my application server?

I've gone through a lot of docs, but it does not seem to be working. I see that while adding a record set, I need to enter the public IP of my ec2 instance in the value field, but how do I get it to route traffic to port 8080 on the box? If I enter a value like a.b.c.d:8080, it errors out saying "The Value field contains invalid characters or is in an invalid format."

Steps I've done so far:

1. Took an ec2 instance, deployed my web app on port 8080. Everything's
   working fine and I can access my app using the public IP (will go
   for an elastic IP later)
2. Registered domain name with Route53.
3. Created a Hosted Zone with the name of a subdomain.
4. Created a Record Set with the following info: 
   Name:  
   Type: A - IPv4 address 
   Alias: No 
   TTL(Seconds): 300 
   Value: <**THIS IS THE MISSING PIECE I GUESS**>
   Routing Policy: Simple

Can someone point me to any documentation for this? It seems to be a straightforward thing, but somehow I cannot find how to link the pieces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't enter your port, just your IP. Your application will then be accessible at: xyz.com:8080

To make it accessible at xyz.com you need to configure a web server (like nginx, apache...) or a proxy that will redirect the requests coming on port 80 to port 8080. 
Django on Nginx with uWSGI: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

You can also make your django app run directly on port 80 but apparently it's a bad idea: [Run Django without Apache using runserver on port 80 and accessible outside LAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670759/run-django-without-apache-using-runserver-on-port-80-and-accessible-outside-lan)

Comment: Seems legit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to point out that [SRV records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) do support port definitions in DNS, but we should not expect browsers (or many clients for that matter) to query for SRV records.